# How to find if a paper is in top 10% most cited articles in a journal?

Tags: publications, journals, bibliometrics, statistics

I saw in some applications that some researchers state that their papers are in top 10% most cited articles, but they never state how they calculated this. I have tried Web of Knowledge and there are some metrics there, but the don't really match the text from those applications. For instance, I found this kind of formulation in one of the applications:

> For the articles published Engineering category in 2015, the average
> number of citations is only 1.22. This article is therefore one of the
> top 10.00% most cited articles published in Engineering in 2015.

I saw that it was calculated using Google Scholar, but I don't know how they do it. Can anyone please help me to understand how can you see if you paper is in top xxx% most cited articles like in the text above? Is there a software for that? Or is there any relation with the h-index that can give that for a certain year?

Comment: Is "Engineering" a category of the journal?

Comment: I'm guessing yes, but I am not sure. In Google Scholar, there is "Engineering and Computer Science" category. I first thought that that's the one, but because I didn't understand it, I just assumed that "Engineering" might be a stand-alone category which is not in GS. 

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en

Comment: Did they mention the SD elsewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: So now it is researchers, and not just administrative staff, who are doing the meaningless bibliometric work?

Answer (score 6):

Go to Web of Knowledge and search by publication name. Then sort by citation count and find the 10% cutoff (e.g. if there have been 10,000 papers published in that journal, then the article with the 1000th highest citation count is the 10% cutoff). Then find the paper you're interested in, and see if it's above or below that 10% cutoff.

Comment: Thanks. Web of Knowledge may now "Publication Title" instead of publication name.

Comment: NB: This requires a subscription, cannot do with a free account.

Answer (score 3):

In [Scopus](https://www.scopus.com/), you can use `SRCID ( 17945 )  AND  PUBYEAR  =  2021` to query all publications from the journal `Bioinformatics` published in 2021. You can then sort by `Cited by (highest)`. Here `17945` is the Source ID. You can find all Source IDs from [Sources](https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri?zone=TopNavBar) located at the page top.